# Code working on emulator but not working on real device

Tags: android

```
public class MySmthng extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String url = "http://108.166.161.206:8826/;stream.mp3";
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
}
```

Hello everyone, 
This is a small code to stream audio. This code runs very fine on Emulator but when I install the apk on my device nothing happens except just launch of the application. Can anyone help me how to fix this kind of problem. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown? Anything in your logs?

Comment: You need to look at the logcat on the device. It should tell you if there are any errors.

Comment: there is no entry in log.. anyone pls help me.. its killing me.. am i d nly 1 encountering such an error.? :( :P

Comment: [ 12-22 11:57:51.020  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
[doRouting]sndDevice=0,mCurSndDevice=-1
[ 12-22 11:57:51.020  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
[SKW]do_route_audio_rpc(0, 1, 0)
[ 12-22 11:57:51.030  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
msm72xx_enable_audpp: 0x0000
[ 12-22 11:57:51.030  1383:0x56a E/AudioService ]
[BTUI] [SCO] ### setMode (0)
[ 12-22 11:57:51.640  1296:0x510 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
setAMPControl(0)
[ 12-22 11:57:51.640  1296:0x510 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
setAMPControl- Mode amp off
[ 12-22 12:05:30.542  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]

Comment: Routing audio to Speakerphone
[ 12-22 12:05:30.542  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
[doRouting]sndDevice=0,mCurSndDevice=0
[ 12-22 12:05:30.562  1296:0x563 E/AudioHardwareMSM72XX ]
setAMPControl(1)
[ 12-22 12:05:31.044  1383:0x58a E/Andy_LockScreen ]
[BTUI] ### LockScreen : isOpen(false)
[ 12-22 12:06:06.132 10670:0x29ae E/carrot   ]
call start again, always isRunning = true

Comment: this is what i got in my logcat today.. i m unable to understand the error.. someone pls reply possible corrections.

Comment: 12-22 12:53:26.454: ERROR/MP3Extractor(34): Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.

Comment: 12-22 12:52:05.045: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(34): Not sending buffering status because duration is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the permissions required set up in the manifest file? Most importantly would be :

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Have a look at this site to see what other permissions you would need : [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

I hope this helps. However since it worked on the emulator, permissions are probably not the issue, it's good to check anyway.